# How to reshape an array of images

Tags: python, arrays, image

I am using python 3.6 version. I have an array of images, 
the array size is (4000,200,200,3) - 4000 images of size (200,200,3).
I am trying to reshape the array such that every two following images will combine into one image of size (200,200,6), so eventually i'll get an array of size (2000,200,200,6).

I tried the following:

```
train = train.reshape(int(train.shape[0]/2),train.shape[1],train.shape[2],2*train.shape[3]);
```

I have got an array of shape (2000,200,200,6) but it seems that the images were not concatenated the way I wanted.

My purpose is to train a deep learning model in which every to images are one sample.
I'm using keras with tensorflow as backend.

The model starts with:

```
model = Sequential(); 
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), strides=(2, 2), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape));
```

And as I said, I wish input_shape to be (200,200,6)

I have built the architecture and than used:

```
num_epoch = 3; batch_size = 32; 
model.fit(x=train, y=y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=num_epoch, verbose=1, shuffle=True);
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: why you want to change the number of channels to 6 !!

Comment: I'm trying to train a deep learning architecture and I want to pass into the net every two images together

Comment: you need to show me train method and how you use mini-batches

Comment: I added it to the question